# LINQ: Convert any empty string to Null

Tags: c#, linq, sqlbulkcopy

I have a list populated with massive amount of data and over hundred columns. I will have to convert the entire list to DataTable and use `SQLBulkCopy` to batch insert all data into the database.

Everything is okay except that some of the fields could be empty. And for some reason, some of the empty fields causes some formatting exception after converted to DataTable and during `SQLBulkCopy` insertion. After some R&D, I found that converting the empty fields to NULL solve the issue for batch insertion using `SQLBulkCopy`.

Is there any way I can use LINQ to find empty fields in the list and convert them to NULL or DBNULL before I convert the list to DataTable?

Even though I'm going to convert the list to DataTable but I don't want to loop each row and each cell to check if the cell is empty and convert to null because it can affect the performance a lot when the data is too much.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: That's about converting an empty *sequence* to a single-item sequence where the item is a default value for the element type. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: Post the table schema, a sample of your data and the full exception. Is it a constraint violation? Invalid cast? Something else? You *don't* have to convert empty strings to NULL, if the underlying table is an `nvarchar` or `varchar` table. Storing null is a hack - instead of solving the problem you don't store anything at all. Applications or queries that expected the field to contain an empty string will crash or produce wrong results

Comment: Are you trying to store strings into numeric fields perhaps?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for pointing out my mistake, incorrect API, meant for Join operations

Comment: Where does the empty string come from? Is it a missing value from a CSV perhaps? In this case, you could modify the csv reading code to return NULLs for missing numeric values, or even convert the values to nullable numbers directly

Answer (score 1):

You're already looping over each column/row combination in order to convert to a `DataTable`, you can add a new parameter to that function, `Func<object, object>` that you execute on each cell and in that function you check if the value is empty, so replace it with *NULL*

```
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(List<T> list, Func<object, object> transform)
{
   // logic
   object value = getUsingReflaction(); // ignore for now

   if(transform != null)
      value = transform(object);
   // continue
}
```

Usage:

```
ConvertToDataTable(myList, o => 
            {
                if (o is string && (string)o == String.Empty)
                    return DBNull.Value;
                else return o;
            });
```

Comment: Why replace anything at all? SqlBulkCopy can store empty strings into text fields. Unless it's a missing value that should be stored in a numeric field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well that's what the OP wants to do.

Comment: The old adage holds - the OP may be asking how to jump off a cliff. Storing a NULL instead of an empty string, when an empty string *is* expected can cause trouble. On the other hand, it the souce data is an optional numeric field from a CSV, why not convert to eg `int?` instead of strings and nulls? Your snippet can produce an actual solution instead of covering up the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He is not jumping off a cliff. There are always many ways to do one thing, I never said that the approach he wants to go with is the best one, but it might be the most efficient one as he's already looping in that method.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer only to the very first part where you can replace all the empty string fields with the Null value using a conditional statment

```
public class Person
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
private static void LinQ3()
{
    var namesList = new List<Person>();
    namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", Name = "Jonh" });
    namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", Name = string.Empty });
    namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", Name = string.Empty });

    var nullV = namesList.Select(x => new {
        Sex=x.Sex,
        nullableName= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name)?null: x.Name
    });
}
```

This will return a list(nullV) where the field "Name" will contain null values for every empty value on the field name.
Also, you have to declare every field that you want to convert the empty strings using the same conditional statement